# Fast Way to Look Up Values Instead of Iterating through a List of Lists of Lists?

Tags: python, search, indexing, data-structures, geospatial

I'll explain the situation first instead of asking the question, for someone may know a better way for me to keep track of my data.

The overall problem is that I want to work with a control net of many images.  The images lay across a planetary surface and have some overlap.  Points exist at a given latitude x longitude.  Measures are instantiations of those points on different images.  Every point must have at least 2 measures (otherwise it's thrown out in other software).  Each measure has a lot of information I need to store (the image it's on, row/col of where the measure is on that image, etc.).  In other software, the control network is already made, what I want to do is write python code to do a lot of stuff with it that the other software isn't made to do.

I have parsed the control network file and read it into a Python list of lists of lists, which may be inelegant, so if someone has a better way to do that, I'm all ears.  Here's an example of what the list[][][] would look like:

```
[
 [[PointID_1, ImageSN_A, line, sample, goodness-of-fit],
  [PointID_1, ImageSN_B, line, sample, goodness-of-fit]]
 [[PointID_2, ImageSN_A, line, sample, goodness-of-fit],
  [PointID_2, ImageSN_B, line, sample, goodness-of-fit]]
]
```

PointID_1 and _2 would be at different locations.

I also have a list that's effectively a cache of ImageSN so I can easily parse through and know what images are in the control network.

And I have a list of lists that's a cache of PointID, where what I'll call a "row" (thinking of it like a spreadsheet) corresponds to that row's index in the ImageSN list, so I can easily figure out what PointIDs are on every single image.

Now for the problem I'm trying to solve quickly:  I want to calculate a rectangular hull ratio, which is the area of the points on the image divided by the area of the image.  My method is, in theory, to iterate through the points that are on each image, find the measure for that point, and get the line/sample and compare that to four variables, the min/max line/sample overall.  So, simply going through the list and figuring out what are the outer-most measures on each image and calculating the area of that versus the area of the image.

Here's my code that *works*:

```
for i in range(0,len(PointIDs)):
    for sublist_cnet_point in CNet:
        for sublist_cnet_measure in sublist_cnet_point:
            if image in sublist_cnet_measure[1]:
                min_line = min(min_line,sublist_cnet_measure[3])
                min_samp = min(min_samp,sublist_cnet_measure[2])
                max_line = max(max_line,sublist_cnet_measure[3])
                max_samp = max(max_samp,sublist_cnet_measure[2])
```

It's very straightforward.  However, it takes a very long time, and I'm testing this on a relatively tiny control net for me (30MB, whereas I'll be dealing with ones >1GB).  This corresponds to 24 images with 64k control points comprising 183k control measures.  The average calculation to go through all these took about two minutes (4GHz processor, no RAM issues), but some took over 20.  This is, as I said, about 1/100th of my actual network.

Meaning, this is untenable.  So, is there a much, much faster way to do this?  If not, the only solution I can think of is to just randomly sample a subset of the PointIDs and hope that they're well enough distributed that the hull ratio will be accurate enough.  I was also thinking about multi-threading, but that doesn't solve the huge scaling issue unless I'm using a computer cluster (which I'm not).

Comment: Your code never uses `i`?

Comment: Um ... wow, okay, yeah, that was it.  Runs now in 0.002–0.1% of the time, same answer.  I hate when I make stupid mistakes.  That said ... Is there a more Python-y way to do this?

Comment: Run an `intertools.product` on the three index ranges.  Loop on the ordered triples, and pull off the three indices for each iteration.

Comment: If you want a fast-lookup hierarchical 2D spatial data-structure, try quadtrees or something similar. (Then also maybe you don't need to store row/col of where the measure is on that image, etc.) Also, why not just call 'measures' 'instances' since they don't require any calculation, unlike say Euclidean or spherical-trigonometry distance.

Comment: @smci: The terminology is not mine, it's set by the United States Geological Survey in their software. I'm using their terms (points/measures) so's not to have different terms in different software.

Comment: @StuartRobbins oh ok, it sounded misleading. Did you look into quadtrees?

Comment: @StuartRobbins are you still interested in an answer?